# Do we need different tag for blocks(s,p,d,f)

Tags: discussion, tags

I know we have [periodic-table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-table) tag but when we learn periodic table, we normally learn specific block instead of whole table together.

So instead of having  [periodic-table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-table), should we split them into 4 tags [s-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/s-block) [p-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-block)[d-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-block)[f-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-block)

Comment: I'm not sure if individual block tags would really be useful, but if we were to use them, we would probably want to still keep the [tag:periodic-table] tag as questions about the table as a whole wouldn't fit into individual blocks, e.g. questions about the table's history, alternate table layouts, group numbering, etc.

Comment: I do not think this is necessary or even useful. Instead it is worthwhile revisiting the tag itself, i.e. defining the scope of it new (in the sense @MichaelD.M.Dryden explained) and retag the remaining questions to more appropriate fits.  For example the d-block tag is synonymous with [tag:transition-metals] and [tag:rare-earth-elements] would be (mostly) synonymous with the f-block tag. For the remaining it would be better to use the group names: alkali-metals, alkaline-earth-metals, triels, tetrels, pnictogens, halogens, [tag:noble-gases].

Comment: Does seem legit for me either, at least for now. Some tags are broad, like the organic-chemistry itself. More specific tags wouldn't look really nice beside the more general ones.

Comment: Dont forget  "g-block". Theres a good chance of questions about that too.

Comment: Those just seem way too specific to me, and of very limited utility.

Comment: And they have a chat room, anyway ;)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the [d-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-block) is already covered by [transition-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition-metals).
Likewise, the [f-block](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-block) is covered by [rare-earth-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rare-earth-metals).

I don’t consider separating s and p-blocks from each other a good idea. If anything, they are similar enough to be termed [main-group-elements](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/main-group-elements). But at the same time, they are also much more diverse within each group when compared to the [transition-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition-metals) or the [rare-earth-metals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rare-earth-metals). What similarities do e.g. indium and sulphur have? Or magnesium and hydrogen? Even within the main groups there is not enough similarity, see for example lead versus carbon or hydrogen versus caesium. If anything, we can use the main group elements to discuss trends in the periodic table — but we already have [periodic-trends](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-trends).

So no, I am very much against creating s or b-block tags.

Comment: Wah o.O Is it some question resurrection?  T'was asked it thr beginning of 2015!

Comment: @Mithoron Didn’t even realise o.o'' Blame the edit O:-)